# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while running project on M1 chip Mac

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

Getting issue while running trying to run the project on the Mac M1. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

I have changes the Excluded Architecture to **arm64** and also added the following lines in the podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

At the last moment project fails with the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SLNavigationTypeExit", referenced from:
      ___46-[RNSmartlook trackNavigationEvent:direction:]_block_invoke in libsmartlook-react-native-bridge.a(RNSmartlook.o)
  "_SLNavigationTypeEnter", referenced from:
      ___46-[RNSmartlook trackNavigationEvent:direction:]_block_invoke in libsmartlook-react-native-bridge.a(RNSmartlook.o)
  "_SLSetupOptionFramerateKey", referenced from:
      ___31-[RNSmartlook setup:framerate:]_block_invoke in libsmartlook-react-native-bridge.a(RNSmartlook.o)
      ___48-[RNSmartlook setupAndStartRecording:framerate:]_block_invoke in libsmartlook-react-native-bridge.a(RNSmartlook.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Build target log

```
 Link PROJECTNAME(x84_64) 1.1 second
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having the same issue with 'smartlook-react-native-wrapper'. Nothing seems to be working